# strtoll not setting errno to ERANGE upon overflow

Tags: c, gcc, linux-mint, errno, strtol

I'm parsing a long long value using `fgets` and `strtoll` as one does, but `strtoll` is not setting `errno` to `ERANGE` when an overflow occurs like it's supposed to.

[From the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol):

> *The `strtol()` function returns the result of the conversion, unless the value would underflow or overflow. If an underflow occurs, `strtol()` returns `LONG_MIN`. **If an overflow occurs, `strtol()` returns LONG_MAX. In both cases, `errno` is set to `ERANGE`. Precisely the same holds for `strtoll()` (with LLONG_MIN and LLONG_MAX instead of LONG_MIN and LONG_MAX)**.*

Sample code without `fgets` for MRE purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){

    long long number; //max value 9223372036854775807   
    char input[] = "12345678976543245678976543";
    char *end;

    number = strtoll(input, &end, 10);

    printf("%d %d <%s> %lld %lld\n", errno, ERANGE, input, (long long)number, LLONG_MAX);
    //prints 0 for errno and 34 for ERANGE regardless of overflow
    //eerno should be set to ERANGE so it should be 34

    int e = errno; //further testing, assigning errno
    printf("%d", e);// again prints 0 should be 34
}
```

Output is:

```
0 34 <12345678976543245678976543> 9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807
0
```

Should be:

```
34 34 <12345678976543245678976543> 9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807
34
```

This is highly confusing to me, especially because [in an online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UyhRFnz3XFEY7pFy) it seems to work fine.

I'm using gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2), ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9) 2.31 in a recently updated Linux Mint 20.

Comment: @sebastian, it seems the problem is confined to my system, ufortunately, if there was someone with the same system here maybe the problem could be pinpointed.

Comment: 32-bit version of MSVC outputs `34 34` for an overrange input so their man page wasn't fully described.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, the ERANGE part is in the [`strtol` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtol-wcstol-strtol-l-wcstol-l?view=vs-2019) they forgot `strtoll`

Comment: Note that on Linux, standard functions like `strtoll` are provided by the standard C library (usually `glibc`), not by the gcc compiler itself.  So focusing on gcc version numbers is not going to get anywhere; look at glibc versions instead.

Comment: It appears this is highly unlikely to be an issue with gcc or glibc (not reproducible). Rather something wrong environment or broken gnu toolchains.

Comment: Note `int e = errno;` should happen before the first `printf()` to eliminate `printf()` as the bad boy.  IOWs, capture `errno` right after `strtoll()`.

Comment: @chux arguments are evaluated *before* the function call  - printf cannot change errno in a way that would affect the print

Comment: Please report it as a bug as it is one! What compiler switches are you using? Mine, Focal plain, are exactly 2.31-0ubuntu9 and 9.3.0-10ubuntu2), and I get 34...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "printf cannot change errno in a way that would affect the print" --> Perhaps, yet there is a bug somewhere.  Just trying to clearly separate candidate contributors.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the entire system and the problem is gone now, I should have maybe reported it, I was thinking about my problems more than in the community.

The likely situation that caused these issues is the fact that I glazed over some of the recommended steps in upgrading my system.

The circumstantial evidence:

- There were other issues like a wifi error, problems with the GRUB and with the timezone, they are also gone after the new instalation.
- I also updgraded my desktop just to see if I could reproduce the same problems, but this time following carefully all the steps and everything works fine.

So for anyone upgrading UNIX systems, ***pay atention to the upgrade instructions***. And have backups, it saved my life in this instance.