# cannot compile on mint 20.1: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, include, linux-mint

I am running a fresh install of Linux Mint 20.1 and I'n trying to compile a program for a GPS tracker, but it won't compile:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:62,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QtCore:4,
                 from pch.h:27:
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   75 | #include_next <stdlib.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have installed a number of additional libraries (`libusb`, `libmarble` and a few others) and `qmake`.

Of course, `stdlib.h` is present on the system:

```
$ find /usr -name stdlib.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h
/usr/include/bsd/stdlib.h
/usr/include/stdlib.h
/usr/include/c++/9/tr1/stdlib.h
/usr/include/c++/9/stdlib.h
/usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl-private/compat/stdlib.h
```

After looking at the other questions about this, I re-installed `build-essential`, which didn't help.

I re-installed the g++ compiler, no luck either.

I copied `/usr/include/c++/9/stdlib.h` to `/usr/local/include`, but it still complains about a missing `stdlib.h`

I changed the

```
#include_next <stdlib.h>
```

in `cstdlib` into

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

only to find that the next include cannot find `stdlib.h`; changing that one produced the third include and so on. So that does not work either.

The program compiles and works on Slackware 14.2 by the way.

What am I missing?

Hello-world compiles normally; a simple program that does a `malloc` also compiles and runs.

Comment: I had some problems too a few months ago in a Linux Mint version upgrade https://stackoverflow.com/q/63537391/6865932, some libraries were exhibiting strange behaviors, not only that but some devices were not working properly, I could only solve it by reinstalling the system, hopefuly you won't need to do that.

Comment: Diagnostic step: is the toolchain hosed or just the specific build misconfigured? Try making a hello world including something from stdlib.h (let's say malloc), compile by hand.

Comment: both work; added it to the question.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/87751/qtcreator-compile-returning-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory/7 <- this looks somewhat relevant - do you have INCLUDEPATH somewhere?

Comment: There were some directories added to the INCLUDEPATH in the Makefile. I tried to compile by hand (`gcc -c xxxx -Idirectory` etc.) but I still got the missing includes.

Answer (score 0):

I used to @anastaciu 's solution.

As it was a fresh install without much customization, I resorted to the option of a complete re-install. Bizarre that that works a bit, as it was already a fresh install. I still had to copy `stdlib.h` and a few others (`math.h  etc.) to` /usr/local/lib` to get to the point where it would at least compile.